# How do fix my Bitbucket ssh access?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have been successfully pulling and pushing to my repo for over a month. My last push was on the 22nd January 2015. All was well.

Today, I tried to push and I got an error:

> conq: repository access denied. fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

However, nothing on my server has changed. I logged into the dash and everything looked fine: commits are there, and the SSH key is in sync with my public key.

Cloning the repository again resulted in the same error. I tried everything I could think of. In the end, I took a backup and reinstalled the OS on the server.

I removed the public key from the dash and added my new public. Still, the same error.

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxxxx/foo.git
```

> Cloning into 'foo'... conq: repository access denied. fatal: Could not
>   read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is this a repo of your own?

Comment: Yes, it my own repo.

Comment: What is the output of `ssh git@bitbucket.org`?

Comment: I worked it out, I had agent forwarding enabled on my ssh client, so it was authenticating with my local ssh key with is registered with a different account.

Comment: @thomas-peter Could you please elaborate? Feel free to add an answer and include as much detail and steps as you like.